# The connection between span and space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have $L=\{p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d \in R_4 | a=2b \mbox{ and } c=d\}$ over $\mathbb R$.
Now I need to find the span of it and prove by it that this $L$ is a space over $\mathbb R$.

So by playing with it I have found that the span is $\{2x^3 + x^2, x+1\}$.

Judging by what we did in class now I would just say "..and therefore $L$ spans $R_4$"

But I don't understand why? I can always find a span for any group of polynomials so does it mean that polynomials will always span $R_4$? I am confused about the connection between spans and spaces.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for my knowledge, What is $R_4$? :)

Comment: You have not found the span (the span would just be the set itself provided it is a subspace). Perhaps you meant to say a basis?

Comment: @H.R. It means a tuple of 4 real numbers (a,b,c,d)

Comment: @MattSamuel I may have meant basis I just can't be sure what is the right word since I try to translate these things from my own language

Comment: You are very confused. ${\bf R}^4$ is not "a tuple of 4 real numbers." It is the set of *all* 4-tuples of real numbers. $L$ might be the span of $\{2x^3+x^2,x+1\}$, but $\{2x^3+x^2,x+1\}$ can't be the span of $L$, or of anything else. And if we are talking about the span of $\{2x^3+x^2,x+1\}$, well, that will be a 2-dimensional vector space, so it can't be ${\bf R}^4$, which is a 4-dimensional vector space. It's really really really important in Linear Algebra to use words with their precise meanings, otherwise you don't have a snowball's chance.

Comment: ^^ Language when learning linear algebra is absolutely crucial. Read Gerry's comment with great care.

Comment: Have you read my answer? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's start with the definitions. The *span* of a set $S=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\}$ is the set of all linear combinations of the elements of $S$, that is, it is the set of all vectors of the form $$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_rv_r$$ where $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_r$ are real numbers. It is easy to check that the span of any set is nonempty and is closed under addition and under multiplication by scalars, so the span of any set is a vector space.

Conversely, given any vector space $V$, there is always a set $S$ such that the span of $S$ is $V$. Indeed, you could just take $S$ to be $V$. But if $V$ is a subspace of ${\bf R}^n$ for some $n$, then there will be sets $S$ with at most $n$ elements such that the span of $S$ is $V$.

Now, in your example, you are talking about vector spaces whose elements are polynomials. So presumably your $R_4$ is the vector space of polynomials of degree at most three. This is not the same as ${\bf R}^4$ (since the elements of ${\bf R}^4$ are 4-tuples, not polynomials), but it is isomorphic to ${\bf R}^4$.

Now it is correct that if $S=\{2x^3+x^2,x+1\}$ then the span of $S$ is your vector space $L$. Indeed, as soon as you know that the span of $S$ is $L$, you know that $L$ is a vector space (by the first paragraph of this answer). But of course $L$ is not all of $R_4$. For example, $x$ is in $R_4$, but not in $L$.

I hope this clarifies things, and I hope you'll think it through until you understand it. If you have further questions after you have thought it through for a while, ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay in my response, I see now my mistakes, but I am still confused by something.

I actually meant that L is a vector space, but I did not understand why finding a span means that something is a vector space.

as you said we can always find a span but its impossible that everything that has a span will be vector space.

I know I don't explain myself too good so if you take the example I gave where a=2b and c=d we found a span and said that L is a vector space, well even if a=c=b=d we could still do it and even if a=5b.
So why is it happening?

Comment: When does finding a span doesn't auto-means that L is a vector space? (cause I am confused by the fact that you can always find span -> and you can always claim that finding a span means L is a vector space)

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you write, "finding a span". The span of a set $S$ is the set of all linear combinations of elements of $S$, and that is guaranteed to be a vector space (and you should be able to work out why the span of $S$ is a always a vector space). Conversely, given a vector space $V$, there is always a set $S$ whose span is $V$. Given a set $T$ that isn't a vector space, it makes no sense to ask for a set $S$ whose span is $T$. Given a set of homogeneous linear equations relating $a,b,c,d$, the 4-tuples satisfying those equations will always form a vector space....

Comment: ...and that's another fact you should be able to prove. And since those 4-tuples form a vector space, there is guaranteed to be a set $S$ spanning that vector space.